# Is it possible to get intellisense for jquery in other js files?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsdoc

I am working on a web page that has a reference to jquery and another js file with custom javascript for that page. Since the custom js file is external it isn't showing me intellisense for jquery. any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it, if jQuery was beside the file in question for example, add this at the top of the file you want intellisense in:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.js" />
```